# Traverse linked list with recursive method

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I need to go through a list linked by the middle of a function with a parameter that is a triple pointer, by means of a recursive void function.

The program is as follows

```
typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node* next;
}Node;

void insert(Node** first,int d){
   Node* new= createNode(d);
   new->next= *first;
   *first=new;
}

Node* createNode(int d){
  Node* new= (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  new->data= d;
  new->next=NULL;
  return new;
}


void printList(Node***p)
{
    Node**temp = *p;

    if(temp == NULL)
       return;
    else
   {
     printf("\nValue: %d", (*temp)->data);

     *temp = (*temp)->next;

     printList(&temp);
  }
}

int main()
{
  Node *first =  NULL;

  int n =10;

  while(n>0){
   insert(&first,n);
   n=n-1;
   }

Nodo **ptr_first= &first;

printList(&ptr_first);

return 0;
}
```

The function prints all the values, but the program hangs and returns a negative value. What is wrong with this implementation?
PD: The use of the triple pointer is only for teaching purposes

Comment: Replace `if(temp == NULL)` with `if(*temp == NULL)`.

Comment: I cannot fathom the reason for triple-indirection in this code. It is completely unnecessary for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion termination condition is wrong.

You have tho change `if(temp == NULL)` to `if(*temp == NULL)`, since `*temp` is pointing to the element and not `temp`.

I also think that it is not good for teaching if you use triple pointers since they are not necessary here.